# CSS3 Background query

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:  I also would like to add a image to the right of that box.  Would I use `background-image?`  The image in question is a close icon.

**CSS:**

```
.scheduledCenter .alertMessage{
    width:100%;
    height:15px;
    color:#3385B2;
    background-color:#D1DEE8;
    border:3px solid #8099B4;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add:

```
background: #D1DEE8 url('../images/icon.png') no-repeat 100% 0;
```

You will get both the icon and the background color.

Comment: Whats the 100% and 0 as I need to pad the image about 5px

Comment: 100% is the horizontal starting point (you can specify it in px) and 0 the vertical starting point.